# How to refill a dropdown after emptying it using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two dropdowns and i empty it by using:

```
document.getElementbyId("select1").options.length = 0;
```

when the other is changed. How can I refill it with old values using javascript?

Comment: Well you would need to have the data to add in.

Comment: @epascarello not sure what you mean, the OP tells us that the data is the old values (from before the select was emptied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by saving the `innerHTML` to a variable before clearing it out like this:

**Plain Javascript**

```
<script>

// Save it
var old_options = document.getElementbyId("select1").innerHTML;

// Clear it
document.getElementbyId("select1").options.length = 0;

// Refill it
document.getElementbyId("select1").innerHTML = old_options;

</script>
```

If it is available to you then I highly recommend jQuery.

**jQuery version**

```
<script>

// Save it
var old_options = $('#select1').html();

// Clear it
$('#select1').html('');

// Refill it
$('#select1').html(old_options);

</script>
```

Comment: I don't have any idea how to use jquery, so I prefer js, but I will try this.

Comment: I can update my post with jQuery version as well, it might be of valuable interest.

Answer (score 1):

Clone your original select before emptying it:

```
var mySelect=document.getElementById("select1");
var savedSelect=mySelect.cloneNode(true);
```

Later, you can push the savedSelect options back to the original select, for example with a loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<savedSelect.options.length;i++) {
    mySelect.appendChild(savedSelect.options[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

There are other copy options, for example the use of a document fragment. Note that innerHTML doesn't work with select elements in IE.